Connection issue with an healthy Docker Compose Postgres container
I've a very weird and random issue that's affecting my system (Ubuntu/Pop!_OS) using Docker Compose and some services, in particular, I'm facing an issue with a Postgres (postgres:16) image and my connection through the host machine (and also affects docker containers connection).
Let me explain the situation a bit better, the container in question is reachable and I did not understand which circumstance is triggering this problem but surely it's something.
Bare minimum example of the Docker Compose file:
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:16
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - ./.postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:delegated
    user: "${UID:-1000}:${GID:-1000}"
    ports:
      - "5452:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
      POSTGRES_DB: "database"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "psql", "-w", "-U", "postgres", "-c", "SELECT 1" ]
      interval: 1m
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3

When this issue happens, the container just starts regularly and I can see in the logs that's everything is all right:
postgres  | 2024-06-17 21:31:57.676 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.3 (Debian 16.3-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
postgres  | 2024-06-17 21:31:57.676 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres  | 2024-06-17 21:31:57.676 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres  | 2024-06-17 21:31:57.696 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres  | 2024-06-17 21:31:57.711 UTC [16] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-06-17 21:31:56 UTC
postgres  | 2024-06-17 21:31:57.722 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

But when I try to connect with all clients, I get a generic error connection attempt failed and if even try with telnet I can clearly see:
❯ telnet 127.0.0.1 5452
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

But if I restart my machine, without touching anything, the container accepts connection regularly.
I also tried to restart the Docker service etc, no luck.
